# current_item.quantity += 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running into the following issue while building an ecommerce app through the guidance of Agile 4, in Rails 4.1.4.

After clicking "add to cart", I see this error:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

for:

```
def add_product(product_id)
 current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
if current_item
  current_item.quantity += 1
else
  current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
end
  current_item
end
```

Let me know if there's any other relevant code I can attach.

Comment: that means that `current_item` is returning `nil`. your `line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)` is returning nil. if you have access to `rails c` then this should be figure out why it's failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty common scenario. Instead do:

```
current_item.increment(:quantity)
```

Comment: What does the new method look like with that added?

Comment: Just put this line in place of `current_item.quantity += 1`. It does almost same thing, but it knows to treat nils as zeros.

Comment: This is giving me an improper count, 1 product shows as "x product", and two shows as "1x" product. Insight?

Comment: This is weird. What is in your database? Also please post the code which displays those values.

Comment: the view: <li><%= item.quantity %> <%=item.product.name %></li>.  I have default :1 for quantity in my line_items table, as requested by the book, could that be it?

Comment: Could you insert `raise current_item.inspect` line before the line from the solution and paste the error message here. Then move `raise` after this line and paste result as well. We'll get to the bottom of this. :)

Comment: here is before the line's error: #<LineItem id: 27, name: nil, price: nil, quantity: 2, order_id: nil, color: nil, created_at: "2014-08-06 21:32:41", updated_at: "2014-08-06 21:37:06", product_id: 1, cart_id: 27>

Comment: and here is after : #<LineItem id: 27, name: nil, price: nil, quantity: 3, order_id: nil, color: nil, created_at: "2014-08-06 21:32:41", updated_at: "2014-08-06 21:37:06", product_id: 1, cart_id: 27>

Comment: Is there a chance that product is called 'x product'?

Comment: no, because when I removed the &times from the view, same issue, 2=1 for some reason

Comment: Ah, note that there is no `&times` in the view code you posted. Ok than, I will need to see your controller action. Most likely it is caused by execution order.

Comment: from line_items #create:   :product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

Comment: And we are getting somewhere. You didn't mention anything about cart model before. We are incrementing quantity of the object but we are not saving it. Try using `increment!` (banged version) instead.

Comment: substitute that whole line with just "increment!"?

Comment: just add the bang sign.

Comment: Please place all these tips inside the answer. It would be helpful to know why you chose this method.